# Getting TTFB (time till first byte) for an HTTP Request

Tags: python, http, urllib2

Here is a python script that loads a url and captures response time:

```
import urllib2
import time

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
request = urllib2.Request('http://example.com')

start = time.time()
resp = opener.open(request)
resp.read()
ttlb = time.time() - start
```

Since my timer is wrapped around the whole request/response (including read()), this will give me the TTLB (time to last byte).

I would also like to get the TTFB (time to first byte), but am not sure where to start/stop my timing.  Is urllib2 granular enough for me to add TTFB timers?  If so, where would they go?

Answer (score 11):

you should use `pycurl`, not `urllib2`

1. install `pyCurl`:
   you can use pip / easy_install, or install it from source.

   easy_install pyCurl

   maybe you should be a superuser.
2. usage:

   ```
   import pycurl
   import sys 
   import json

   WEB_SITES = sys.argv[1]

   def main():
       c = pycurl.Curl()
       c.setopt(pycurl.URL, WEB_SITES)              #set url
       c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)  
       content = c.perform()                        #execute 
       dns_time = c.getinfo(pycurl.NAMELOOKUP_TIME) #DNS time
       conn_time = c.getinfo(pycurl.CONNECT_TIME)   #TCP/IP 3-way handshaking time
       starttransfer_time = c.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)  #time-to-first-byte time
       total_time = c.getinfo(pycurl.TOTAL_TIME)  #last requst time
       c.close()

       data = json.dumps({'dns_time':dns_time,         
                          'conn_time':conn_time,        
                          'starttransfer_time':starttransfer_time,    
                          'total_time':total_time})
       return data

   if __name__ == "__main__":    
       print main()
   ```

Comment: Why is starttransfer_time which is TTFB different from the one I see in developer tools of chrome... this script returns 1.4s where as chrome shows 480ms

Answer (score 2):

Using your current `open` / `read` pair there's only one other timing point possible - between the two.

The `open()` call should be responsible for actually sending the HTTP request, and should (AFAIK) return as soon as that has been sent, ready for your application to actually read the response via `read()`.

Technically it's probably the case that a long server response would make your application block on the call to `read()`, in which case this isn't TTFB.

However if the amount of data is small then there won't be much difference between TTFB and TTLB anyway.  For a large amount of data, just measure how long it takes for `read()` to return the first smallest possible chunk.

Comment: thanks.  doing something like "connection time" for the open step might get me what I need (though not really TTFB)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the implementation of HTTP opening in urllib2 has no callbacks when read is performed. The OOTB opener for the HTTP protocol is `urllib2.HTTPHandler`, which uses `httplib.HTTPResponse` to do the actual reading via a socket.

In theory, you could write your own subclasses of HTTPResponse and HTTPHandler, and install it as the default opener into urllib2 using [install_opener](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). This would be non-trivial, but not excruciatingly so if you basically copy and paste the current HTTPResponse implementation from the standard library and tweak the `begin()` method in there to perform some processing or callback when reading from the socket begins.

Answer (score 1):

To get a good proximity you have to do read(1). And messure the time.

It works pretty well for me.
The ony thing you should keep in mind: python might load more than one byte on the call of read(1). Depending on it's internal buffers. But i think the most tools will behave alike inaccurate.

```
import urllib2
import time

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
request = urllib2.Request('http://example.com')

start = time.time()
resp = opener.open(request)
# read one byte
resp.read(1)
ttfb = time.time() - start
# read the rest
resp.read()
ttlb = time.time() - start
```