# Python: Get time to last byte for HTTP request

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I want to get the time to last byte (TTLB) for HTTP request. I have tried the below:

1) **requests.elapsed** - but this returns the time just after the header finishes loading

2) **requests** (from [Measuring the HTTP response time with requests library in Python. Am I doing it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442757/measuring-the-http-response-time-with-requests-library-in-python-am-i-doing-it)) - this works, however I am expecting a time of 3 seconds, not 0.5 seconds, so I would like to test another method.

3) **urllib** (from [Getting TTFB (time till first byte) for an HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744532/getting-ttfb-time-till-first-byte-for-an-http-request)) - I am behind a proxy and am having difficulties getting the proxy to work. I have tried this ([How can I open a website with urllib via proxy in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168171/how-can-i-open-a-website-with-urllib-via-proxy-in-python)) but it does not work. The error I am getting is: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`. The proxy details I am using are correct (it works in request).

The code I am using:

```
def url_time(url):
    proxydict = {'http': 'http://xxxx', 'https': 'https://xxxx'}

    proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxydict)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    start_time = time.time()
    stream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    output = stream.read()
    end_time = time.time()
    stream.close()

    return end_time-start_time
```

Appreciate if anyone has any ideas on either getting TTLB using requests, or making urllib work behind proxies - I am on Python 3.6. Thank you.